# Amazon SP API how to send offer on existing product

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am working to integrate amazon SP API to send products offers on the platform.
For now, I just need to send an offer for a product already existing on the platform I have the ASIN for the product I wish to offer. The issue is that I can't find a way to just send price and inventory information and the documentation is not all that helpful.
The only endpoint that seems to send product information is [this one](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/blob/main/models/listings-items-api-model/listingsItems_2020-09-01.json).
However, I can't find a way to send pricing info with the product.

The pricing endpoint seems to be there only to get price ? I don't think that's to update pricing information.

It seems easy on the old API but on the new one it's not clear at all.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find the good way to do it ?